# Determine if a Java 8 DateTimeFormatter includes enough timezone information

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timezone, timezone-offset

I have some code that receives a parsed `DateTimeFormatter` instance.
Now in some cases I have seen that there is no timezone/offset information in there and thus I run into parsing errors (exceptions).

To avoid those errors I want to 'force' a default timezone/offset in like `ZoneOffset.UTC` when nothing is specified.

So far I have not yet been able to find a 'clean and documented' way of doing this.

In this example the `getZone()` method returns `null`

```
ParseCaseSensitive(false)Value(DayOfMonth,2)'/'Text(MonthOfYear,SHORT)'/'Value(Year,4)' 'Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)':'Value(SecondOfMinute,2)'.'Value(MilliOfSecond,3)' 'Offset(+HHMM,'+0000')
```

The best I have come up with so far is to do a 'toString()' and then check if a desired substring is in there like this:

```
String formatterExpression = formatter.toString();
if (formatterExpression.lastIndexOf("Offset(") == -1 &&
    formatterExpression.lastIndexOf("ZoneText(") == -1
    ) {
    formatter = formatter.withZone(defaultZone);
    LOG.error("The timestamp format \"{}\" does NOT contain a timezone so we assume \"{}\".",
        formatter.toString(), defaultZone.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

***Additional background information***
This code is part of a system that allows parsing date/time text for which the format was specified using the strftime format.

See:

- https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser/blob/master/httpdlog/httpdlog-parser/src/main/antlr4/nl/basjes/parse/strftime/StrfTime.g4
- https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser/blob/master/httpdlog/httpdlog-parser/src/main/java/nl/basjes/parse/httpdlog/dissectors/StrfTimeToDateTimeFormatter.java

Comment: Do you mean you receive a `DateTimeFormatter` object produced from one of the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` methods (after this has parsed the format pattern string)? Or do you mean that you receive a `TemporalAccessor` that comes from one of the `DateTimeFormatter.parse` methods? Sorry, it’s not perfectly clear.

Comment: IMHO your idea to "serialize" formatters is not a good idea. It was a wise design decision not to make `DateTimeFormatter` serializable. Instead of "formatting" and "reparsing" inherently complex objects like formatters, you could better just send the format pattern strings together with a zone-id and maybe a locale, too, so the receiver can easily reconstruct the original formatter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you mean, and I haven’t found the perfect solution either, but I thought I’d share a couple of options.

If it’s OK for you to set an offset like UTC to be used if the formatter cannot parse a zone or offset, I suggest:

```
formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(formatter)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, ZoneOffset.UTC.getTotalSeconds())
        .toFormatter();
```

I have not yet found a case where this would do any harm. If the formatter already parses zone or offset information (or contains a default offset), this will have no effect. If it doesn’t, the specified default offset will be used.

The above doesn’t work for enforcing a time zone with variable offset (like a time zone with summer time (DST)). To enforce one, I believe you’re supposed to parse, get and catch the exception and then enforce the time zone the way you have already found:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime;
try {
    dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
} catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
    dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, 
                    formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")));
}
```

The downside is that catch clause will also catch errors not related to missing offset or zone. You might try to parse the exception message, but I believe that that just leaves you with a problem similar to the one you started out from. I would not bother.

IMHO what we are really missing is a getter to get the fields that the formatter knows how to format and parse. For complicated formatters, the design and use of such a method would be challenging, though, so I tend to understand why they didn’t provide one.

Comment: Having a simple "fixed" offset like UTC is fine so I really like the parseDefaulting construct. Is it possible to detect that it will be/is used so I can give a warning message?

Comment: Not really (that I know of). A hack may be to default to an odd offset that would otherwise never be used, like 7 seconds or 60013 seconds, then after parsing you can detect if this offset was used (and change to UTC if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been asked a long time ago, but in case someone else needs it, this is the approach I took facing the same problem:

```
public boolean formatterOutputsOffset(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter) {
        DateTimeFormatter forTest = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(dateTimeFormatter)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
                .toFormatter();
        String dateTime = forTest.format(Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        try {
            OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTime, forTest);
            return true;
        } catch (DateTimeException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here I'm testing if the the formatter can convert the current instant into a date string that it can convert back into OffsetDateTime. The parseDefaulting methods are invoked in case the formatter loses the hour, minute or second information which are required for the conversion back to OffsetDateTime. In case you expect loss of year, month or day you can add the corresponding parseDefaulting(...).

The method checks for the pattern availability of an offset, if you need a test for zones you can write practically the same method using ZonedDateTime.parse(...)